# ANTLR Infinite recursion without warning trying to implement macro parsing grammar

Tags: java, antlr4

Antlr will show zero warnings when this grammar is compiled but when called with input file, it will recurse forever in `org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.LexerATNSimulator.closure`. Any idea how to create macro parsing grammars that have to operate on lexers with any characters except special ones?

Lexer:

```
lexer grammar e8pp_lexer;

NEWLINE: '\r' '\n' | '\n' | '\r';
CONTENT: NEWLINE CONTENTF+;
MACRODEF : NEWLINE 'MACRO' -> pushMode(MACRO_DEF);
MACROUSE : NEWLINE '`' -> mode (MACRO_USE); 
fragment CONTENTF: .* ;

mode MACRO_DEF;

MACRONAME: LETTERS+ ;
MACROPARAMSTART: '[' ;
MACROPARAM: LETTERS+ ;
MACROSEP: ',';
MACROPARAMEND : ']' ;
MACRODEF_DEF : ':' -> pushMode(MACRO_MODE);
WHITESPACE: WS+ -> skip;

fragment WS: [ \t\r\n\u000C];
fragment LETTERS : [a-zA-Z];

mode MACRO_MODE;

NEWLINE_CONTENT: '\r' '\n' | '\n' | '\r';
ENDMACRO : NEWLINE_CONTENT 'ENDMACRO' -> popMode;
MACRO_CONTENT : NEWLINE_CONTENT MACRO_CONTENTF+;
fragment MACRO_CONTENTF: .* ;

mode MACRO_USE;

MU_ID: LETTERS+ ;
MU_PARAMSTART: '(';
MU_PARAM: LETTERS+;
MU_PARAMSEP : ',';
MU_PARAM_END: ')' -> popMode;

fragment MU_WS: [ \t\r\n\u000C];
fragment MU_LETTERS : [a-zA-Z];
```

Parser

```
grammar e8pp_parser;

options { tokenVocab=e8pp_lexer; }

content:
    contentElement+ EOF
    ;

contentElement:
    data | macro
    ;

data:
    contentData | macroUse
    ;

contentData:
    CONTENT
    ;

macroUse:
    MACROUSE macroId MU_PARAMSTART macroUseParams? MU_PARAM_END
    ;

macroId:
    MU_ID
    ;

macroUseParams:
    macroUseParam (MU_PARAMSEP macroUseParam)*
    ;

macroUseParam:
    MU_PARAM
    ;


macro:
    MACRODEF macroName 
        MACROPARAMSTART macroParams? MACROPARAMEND MACRODEF_DEF
    macroBody?
    NEWLINE_CONTENT ENDMACRO
    ;

macroName:
    MACRONAME
    ;

macroParams:
    macroParam (MACROSEP macroParam)*
    ;

macroParam:
    MACROPARAM
    ;

macroBody:
    MACRO_CONTENT+
    ;
```

The idea is that this will parse special blocks with macros while returning everything else as data. Java usage:

```
private ByteArrayInputStream parseMacros() throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    e8pp_lexer lexer = new e8pp_lexer(new ANTLRFileStream(srcFile.getAbsolutePath(), "utf-8"));
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    e8pp_parserParser parser = new e8pp_parserParser(tokens);

    ContentContext cc = parser.content();

    Map<String, MacroDef> macros = new HashMap<String, MacroDef>();

    for (ContentElementContext ctx : cc.contentElement()) {
        parseMacroElement(ctx, bos, macros);
    }

    return new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
}

private void parseMacroElement(ContentElementContext ctx, ByteArrayOutputStream bos, Map<String, MacroDef> macros) throws Exception {
    if (ctx.data() != null) {
        if (ctx.data().contentData() != null) {
            bos.write(ctx.data().contentData().getText().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        } else {
            resolveMacro(ctx.data().macroUse(), bos, macros);
        }
    } else {
        defineMacro(ctx.macro(), macros);
    }
}

private void defineMacro(MacroContext macro, Map<String, MacroDef> macros) {
    String name = macro.macroName().getText();
    if (macros.containsKey(name)) {
        throw new AssemblyException("Duplicate macro name " + name);
    }

    MacroDef md = new MacroDef();
    md.content = macro.macroBody().getText();
    md.argNames = parseMacroArgs(macro.macroParams());

}

private List<String> parseMacroArgs(MacroParamsContext ctx) {
    List<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (MacroParamContext p : ctx.macroParam()) {
        params.add(p.getText());
    }

    return params;
}

private void resolveMacro(MacroUseContext ctx, ByteArrayOutputStream bos, Map<String, MacroDef> macros) throws Exception {
    String macroName = ctx.macroId().getText();
    if (!macros.containsKey(macroName)) {
        throw new AssemblyException("Unknown macro " + macroName);
    }

    MacroDef md = macros.get(macroName);
    List<String> values = parseMacroParams(ctx.macroUseParams());

    if (values.size() != md.argNames.size()) {
        throw new AssemblyException("Bad macro param count for macro " + macroName);
    }

    String replaced = md.content;
    for (int i=0; i<md.argNames.size(); i++) {
        String paramName = md.argNames.get(i);
        String replaceValue = values.get(i);
        replaced = replaced.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(paramName), replaceValue);
    }

    bos.write(replaced.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
}

private List<String> parseMacroParams(MacroUseParamsContext ctx) {
    List<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (MacroUseParamContext p : ctx.macroUseParam()) {
        params.add(p.getText());
    }

    return params;
}
```

Comment: I can't help you with your problem. But if you want to create a own grammar + language you should definitly take a look to xtext: https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/
Its based on antlr and in my opinion it easier to use as plain antlr.

Comment: First, looks like you are using an older version of Antlr4. Best to update to the latest, just because. Second, there appear to be problems with your lexer: the rule fragment `fragment CONTENTF: .* ;` will consume content to EOF!  Debug the lexer independently by dumping the token stream and ensuring that the lexer grammar is correctly identifying tokens.